# Android Camera - Taking multiple pictures in succession

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to take 10 pictures as fast as possible after clicking the "Take Picture" button just once.

I tried doing a `for` loop around `Camera.takePicture()`, but realized my mistake fairly quickly. It was calling `takePicture()` before the callback was ready and crashed the program.

I then tried playing around with Threads, monitor objects, etc, but it didn't work as well as I'd like.

Then, I tried calling `takePicture()` from within the JPG PictureCallback `onPictureTaken()` method, hoping to do it recursively. It works, but very slowly. It's not fast at all.

How would you guys go about taking multiple pictures with MINIMUM delay between each picture?

Comment: How slow is "very slowly?" I'd be surprised if you get more than one pic/second. Keep in mind that these cameras simply aren't fast. You might have to reduce resolution to improve performance.

Comment: If I needed to take fast pictures, I'd take video and then write individual frames to jpgs afterward.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. Except I'm not using JPGs due to the compression artifacts. I'm using BMPs. Even with a lot of additional processing, I'm getting around 2 pictures per second. So I guess it's just a hardware limitation more than a software limitation. No reason to complain, I suppose, haha!